# What is the better for performance: set all dom events at once, or progressively?

Tags: javascript, performance, events, dom-events

Is it better to add events listeners once and for all? Or just before an event is likely to happen?

An example: imagine you have a menu in your HTML, which opens on click. You have also a close button in this menu, which closes the menu on click. The event listener on the close button should be set: at page load or only when the menu opens?

In other words, is this:

```
function open() {
  closeButton.addEventListener('click', close);
  // ...
}
function close() {
  closeButton.removeEventListener('click', close);
  // ...
}
openButton.addEventListener('click', open);
```

better/faster than just this?

```
function open() {
  // ...
}
function close() {
  // ...
}
openButton.addEventListener('click', open);
closeButton.addEventListener('click', close);
```

I always prefer to choose simplicity over performance, but does it make a difference at all? Especially when there are lots of events in the UI?

Comment: I think it's pretty safe to assume that doing something once is more efficient than doing it multiple times.

Comment: Yes, but open, close, and reopen the menu multiple times is unlikely. On the contrary, never click on the menu is a strong possibility.

Comment: Your comment helps demonstrate that, as with most performance-related questions, the answer is *"it depends"*. That said, I'd still bind it. I have a hard time believing that adding a handler to an element that exists anyway is going to make any meaningful difference. Set everything up and you're good to go. Low maintenance, low complexity, fewer things to go wrong.

Comment: it doesn't matter. at all. subscribing events doesn't take much horsepower. only rarely does it matter, like grids of onmousover events.

Answer (score 1):

When we know that a event is unlikely to happen untile a certain dependent event, we should defer the event binding. That way the DOM is less heavy

As for the simplicity part, we can have simplified version of code even for he deferred binding of events

Comment: How could we know that the extra work is worth the shot? Is it a good practice to always defer event, or we should keep such an optimisation for heavy UI?

Comment: If you were truly worried about the DOM being "less heavy", then you'd not create the menu to begin with, but rather create and destroy the whole thing on demand. Just focusing on the binding aspect would seem an odd placement of one's attention in dealing with the problem. But again, this comes with overhead. There is no one, right answer for problems like this. Decisions are made case-by-case.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your opinion on that matter!

I'm settling to this: bind directly for click and other obvious actions, and bind later for keyboard and mouse events.

In the example, if we want to close the menu when the user press Escape, then we add the event listener on the keydown event to test `e.key === "Escape"` only when the menu is open. And we remove that listener when the menu is closed.